# Most elegant way to copy POD struct/vector of structs to vector<unsigned char>

Tags: c++, serialization, stl

normally I am using something like

```
copy((uint8_t*)&POD, (uint8_t*)(&POD + 1 ), back_inserter(rawData));

copy((uint8_t*)&PODVec[0], (uint8_t*)(&PODVec[0] + PODVec.size()), back_inserter(rawData));
```

but I am not huge fan of this solution. Any nicer way to do this?

Comment: The ends of the ranges look suspicious... other than that, this looks about it... (as in, AFAIK there is no other way to do this...)

Comment: @Nim i looked at the vector during debugging, looks correct num of bytes was inserted, but ofc I could be wrong... damn you pointer arithmetics!!! :P

Comment: Be aware of possible endianness issues if you save it or send via network...

Comment: @Jarod42 x86 <3 but yeah you are right... ntohl and friends :)

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl actually, the ends look okay, the arithmetic is on the type of the `POD` so `&POD + 1` should do the right thing.. normally, I would do `auto p = reinterpret_cast<>(&POD);`, then `copy(p, p + sizeof(POD), ...);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a pair of helper functions to hide the ugly casts and pointer arithmetics:

```
template<typename T>
char* object_begin(T& obj)
{
    return
        &const_cast<char&>(
            reinterpret_cast<const volatile char&>(obj)
        );
}

template<typename T>
char* object_end(T& obj)
{
    return object_begin(obj) + sizeof(obj);
}
```

You'd use them like this:

```
vector<POD> vpod;
vector<unsigned char> vbytes;

copy(object_begin(vpod.front()),
     object_end(vpod.back()),
     back_inserter(vbytes));
```

Comment: cute :) , but why oh why the volatile ? and references

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl I'm casting to `char&` because in a case of overloaded `operator&` (unlikely, I admit), `&obj` might not work. `volatile` and `const` are there because you can't cast away qualifiers but you can add them. This way it's guaranteed to work if `T` is either const, volatile, both or not qualified.

Comment: great reason, makes sense

Comment: btw should return value be const char* const, i know if it was const char it would not matter but since it is pointer i guess it matters

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl I guess you're right. You can also overload it and make return type be based on qualification of the argument.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, after many tests, `memcpy` is probably the fastest of the copy functions.

Second, you could us this for a single item:

```
rawData = *reinterpret_cast<POD*>(&PODVec[0]);
```

It will reinterpret the byte array address as an object of POD and assign to it using the assignment operator of the class.

This is possible because of section 3.9 of the standard stating:

> For any object (other than a base-class subobject) of trivially
>   copyable type T, whether or not the object holds a valid value of type
>   T, the underlying bytes  making up the object can be copied into
>   an array of char or unsigned char. If the content of the array of
>   char or unsigned char is copied back into the object, the object shall
>   subsequently hold its original value.

Comment: im trying to put stuff into rawData, not the other way around :)

Comment: btw i remember STL guy from MS talking how they use memcpy in STL when appropriate, so it would be nice to see asm code... ofc in theory since I dont speak asm :)

Comment: Upvoting for the useful reference to the standard.

Comment: Notice that implementations are allowed to implement std::copy in terms of memcpy/memmove when appropriate. Libstdc++ does that.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1. Resize vector to proper size

Step 2. Use `memcpy` as you are dealing with raw data

```
#include <vector>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    struct Foo {
        int a;
        double z;
    };

    Foo data[12];
    std::vector<char> rawdata;

    rawdata.resize(sizeof(data));
    memcpy(data, &rawdata[0], sizeof(data));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You want `&rawdata[0]` to be the destination.

Comment: You have the source and dest parameters on `memcpy` reversed.